# CSV File Import Error - Question Marks / Brackets Everywhere

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, xml

I have a few .csv files that were sent to me, but when I try to import them either as .txt files or as .xml files I only get blocks of question marks (?) and brackets (CONTENTS) of the type that would usually be found in an xml file.  All of this appears in Column A of the Excel workbook upon my opening the file.  I am not familiar with xml schemas and so don't know how to approach this problem.  Am I overlooking a simple way for Excel parse the contents of these .csv files?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a CSV at all, so perhaps it was incorrectly created.  Just for fun, try changing the extension to .xlsx and opening with excel.  Perhaps it's actually excel and someone just changed the extension.

Comment: @Madball73 Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately I get an error saying that the .xlsx extension is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean literally what you have written, there's no need to rename the file to either .txt or .xml to open it as those file formats, just open the csv with the .csv extension within excel and it'll work straight away.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that after opening the file as a .csv resulted in an error I tried importing those two ways to see if they would work any better.

Comment: What happens when you open it with notepad?

Comment: In notepad it comes out exactly the same way as in Excel.

Comment: Then it sounds like your CSV file is not formatted correctly or is corrupt. If the CSV file was populated correctly with the right data, it would literally display comma separated values in notepad. If it does not, then the file is broken for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm that.  It's almost surely a problem with the file, right?

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To split the data across multiple columns...

Highlight the cells in column A that contain data. Go to the Data tab and select "Text to columns."

That will bring up a step-by-step wizard that will allow you separate the data into columns. You can start a new column based on a specified width or a particular character (angle brackets or spaces, e.g.).